# When scraping data, I get only first result despite using Array.from

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I want to scrap data from a webpage. Here's the code I have. It is supposed to get all the authors, but it only gets a first one ('Simon Butler').

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#author-group'))
  .map(e =>
      e.querySelector('[class="button-link workspace-trigger button-link-primary"]'))
  .map(e =>
      e.querySelector('[class="button-link-text"]'))
  .map(e =>
      e.querySelector('[class="react-xocs-alternative-link"]'))
  .map(e =>
      e.querySelector('[class="given-name"]').textContent + ' '
      + e.querySelector('[class="text surname"]').textContent)
  .join(', ')
```

As I see it, the error is from using `querySelector` as it gets the first element. However, when I use `querySelectorAll` I get the following error: `e.querySelectorAll is not a function`.

I want to scrap data from https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0164121219302262.
I didn't give any HTML code as the source HTML is really huge when it comes to a portion of authors information. I'm not familiar enough with HTML nor JS to give a minimal sample of HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#author-group'))
> ```

This creates an array with one element in it.

---

The code you provided used `querySelector` which only returned one item (which is what you said you weren't looking for) but you said you tried with `querySelectorAll`.

> ```
> .map(e =>
>       e.querySelectorAll('[class="button-link workspace-trigger button-link-primary"]'))
> ```

Since the previous step returned an array with an element in it, `e` is an element.

Elements have `querySelectorAll` so this is fine.

However, now you are returning a NodeList, not an Element.

---

> .map(e =>
> e.querySelectorAll('[class="button-link-text"]'))

Now `e` is a NodeList. It isn't an Element.

NodeLists **don't** have `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll` methods.

You need to loop over the NodeList (perhaps with a `map`) and deal with each element one by one.

---

Probably what you should be doing is calling `querySelectorAll` **once** and using [descendant combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) to describe the elements containing each author in a **single** query.

Then you would be able to:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#author-group etc etc etc'))
    .map(e =>  
        e.querySelector('[class="given-name"]').textContent
        + ' '
        + e.querySelector('[class="text surname"]').textContent
    )
```

Comment: Please don't use `[class="given-name"]` when `.given-name` exists

Answer (score 1):

There's only one `#author-group`. The elements containing authors are `#author-group button`. The name elements are `.given-name` and `.surname`.

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#author-group button'))
.map(e =>
  e.querySelector('.given-name').textContent + ' '
  + e.querySelector('.surname').textContent)
.join(', ')
```

Have a look at a [CSS Selector reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php) to learn how they work. Ctrl-F in the Elements view of Chrome's developer tools (F12) lets you test selectors.

You can also use `textContent` of an element containing all the elements you want. `#author-group button` contains some extra letters, but `#author-group .react-xocs-alternative-link` contains just the names.

```
Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll(
    '#author-group .react-xocs-alternative-link'
  )
).map(e => e.textContent).join(', ')
```